# How to zip few observables in Kotlin language with RxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, rx-android, rx-kotlin

I have some problem. I'm a beginer in RxJava/RxKotlin/RxAndroid, and dont understand some features. For Example:

```
import rus.pifpaf.client.data.catalog.models.Category
import rus.pifpaf.client.data.main.MainRepository
import rus.pifpaf.client.data.main.models.FrontDataModel
import rus.pifpaf.client.data.product.models.Product
import rx.Observable
import rx.Single
import rx.lang.kotlin.observable
import java.util.*


class MainInteractor {

    private var repository: MainRepository = MainRepository()

    fun getFrontData() {

        val cats = getCategories()
        val day = getDayProduct()
        val top = getTopProducts()

        return Observable.zip(cats, day, top, MainInteractor::convert)
    }

    private fun getTopProducts(): Observable<List<Product>> {
        return repository.getTop()
                .toObservable()
                .onErrorReturn{throwable -> ArrayList() }

    }

    private fun getDayProduct(): Observable<Product> {
        return repository.getSingleProduct()
                .toObservable()
                .onErrorReturn{throwable -> Product()}

    }

    private fun getCategories(): Observable<List<Category>> {
        return repository.getCategories()
                .toObservable()
                .onErrorReturn{throwable -> ArrayList() }
    }

    private fun convert(cats: List<Category>, product: Product, top: List<Product>): FrontDataModel {

    }
}
```

Then I'm use **MainInteractor::convert** Android studio tell me next

[image]

I tried a lot of variant and tried to understand what does it want, but no success. Help me please... Best Regards.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just replace function reference with lambda:

```
return Observable.zip(cats, day, top, { c, d, t -> convert(c, d, t) })
```

And don't forget to declare function's return type explicitly:

```
fun getFrontData(): Observable<FrontDataModel> {
    ...
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also explicitly specify the Function3 type in the lambda Like :

```
Observable.zip(cats,
               day,
               top,
               Function3<List<Product>, Product, List<Category>, FrontDataModel> 
                         { cats, day, top -> convert(cats, day, top) }
```

and play with the IntelliJ idea shortcut [alt+enter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html) to display more actions and change the displaying format of the high-order function.

[image]

**Why Function3?**

Following The Functional Interfaces if it has two Input params it's a [BiFunction](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/BiFunction.html) and if it has 3 Inputs it's a [Function3](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/Function3.html) and the list goes on.

Answer (score -1):

This code worked for me with RXJAVA2

```
    for (i in dbCharacters) {
           // LoadImageToDBS(getApplication<Application>().applicationContext, i, this)
            //   charList.characterList[i.id!!].imageRawData = dbCharacters[i.id!!].imageRawData

            observable =
                    fetcher.loadImage(i.url)
                            .doOnSubscribe {
                                disposable.add(it)
                            }

            singleImageList.add(observable)

            observable.subscribe(object : DisposableSingleObserver<Bitmap>() {
                override fun onSuccess(t: Bitmap) {
                    Log.d("Image", "onSuccess")
                    i.imageRawData = bitMapToString(t)
                    updateCharacter(i)
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("Image Loading Error",e.message)
                }

            })
      }

        Single.zip(singleImageList, { args -> Arrays.asList(args) })
                .subscribe(
                        {
                            Log.d("Zip", "Zip Success")
                            countryLoadError.value = false
                            loading.value = false
                        },{
                    val c = it
                }
                )
```